# @Singleton vs @Producer vs @Singleton @Producer

Tags: singleton, quarkus

I can't understand how the following combinations over the abc method differ: @Singleton vs. @Producer vs. @Singleton @Producer. We are talking about quarkus.

```
// 1
public class Configuration {

    @Produces
    public MyBean abc() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

// 2
public class Configuration {

    @Singleton
    public MyBean abc() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

// 3
public class Configuration {

    @Singleton
    @Produces
    public MyBean abc() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Please explain. You can make analogies with spring.

Answer (score 4):

The first alternative declares a bean with the `@Dependent` scope; it is as if the method was annotated `@Produces @Dependent`.

The 2nd alternative is not valid per strict CDI rules, but Quarkus allows it as a shortcut. It is equivalent to the 3rd alternative, see https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#simplified-producer-method-declaration